# The discrete theory of compressible fluids dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, discrete-geometry, computational-geometry, na.numerical-analysis, mathematical-modeling

I am working on the discrete theory of compressible fluids dynamics, i.e., numerically solving and simulating the compressible fluids , we are interested in the way using discrete exterior calculus, my question is: Is there any work on the discrete theory (especially using discrete exterior calculus) of compressible fluids?

Comment: http://pra.aps.org/abstract/PRA/v46/i4/p1967_1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's unpublished work by Gay-Balmaz and Pavlov, *Variational Discretization of Compressible Fluids*, described [here](http://d-pavlov.com/resources/Research_Statement.pdf), with an instructive summary of the difficulties involved in extending the discrete theory from incompressible to compressible fluids.